# Laravel: How to write two query in one query and get result from database?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, eloquent

I have sample code for get all trashed messages current user:

```
$query1 = $inbox->where('recipient', $user_id)
                ->where('trashed_in_recipient', 1)
                ->where('show_in_recipient', '!=', 1)
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                ->paginate($paginate);

$query2 = $inbox->where('sender', $user_id)
                ->where('trashed_in_sender', 1)
                ->where('show_in_sender', '!=', 1)
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                ->paginate($paginate);
```

How can be writed two query in one and get finally result?

Table structure:

[image]

Comment: we need context regarding the tables you are refering to.

Comment: You can see my table structure in updated question! @Thomas Moors

Comment: Are you using SoftDeletes trait?

Comment: Yes I use but not now! I will use it if I need to restore messages @Rajender Joshi

Comment: If you intend to use SoftDeletes, you don’t need trashed_in_recipient and trashed_in_sender columns.

Comment: Ok, Thanks I will delete that columns if I will use SoftDeletes @Rajender Joshi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use functions to define `WHERE` groups:

```
$query = $inbox->where(function($query) use ($user_id) {
    $query->where('recipient', $user_id);
    $query->where('trashed_in_recipient', 1);
    $query->where('show_in_recipient', '!=', 1);
})->orWhere(function($query) use ($user_id) {
    $query->where('sender', $user_id);
    $query->where('trashed_in_sender', 1);
    $query->where('show_in_sender', '!=', 1);
})->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
  ->paginate($paginate);
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks @Syncro! And on last of query can I paginate two query results?

Comment: inside of callback function using var `$user_id` take error: `Undefined variable: user_id`

Comment: Change it to `function($query) (use $user_id)`

Comment: Use `function($query) use ($user_id)` instead of just `function($query)`, sorry :)

Comment: Working @Syncro! Generaly +1 for you )